# Can I set a custom MinWidth for an ApplicationView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Can I set custom ApplicationView MinWidth in my app?
Or Can I disable 500,320 and other, just set MinWidth like my current width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no. The user can always size a view down to the min width (and any size above it). If you don't specify the 320px min in the manifest, you'll default to 500px. If you set 320px, then the user can resize anywhere down to 320. There isn't any way to set a value in between 320 and 500.